# If $n \equiv 1\text{ (mod 3)}$ and $n \equiv 3 \text{ (mod 7)},$ what is $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If $n \equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $n \equiv 3 \pmod 7,$ which of the following is $n$?
>
> $10$, $3$, $1$ or $7$.

I tried to solve this using Euler’s theorem and managed to conclude the following:

We have that $\gcd(n, 3)=1$ and that $\gcd(n, 7)=1$.

Now we get that $\phi(3)=2$ which would imply that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Similarly $\phi(7)=6$ which in turn implies that $n^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7.$

Now this is essentially just Fermat’s Little Theorem since we have the congurences in the form $n^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p.$

However I seem to be a bit stuck afterwards. It would seem that $n=1$ would satisfy the two congurences at least(?).

$1^{6} \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and $1^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$

Also I’m aware that we could show this just by concluding:

$n \equiv 1 \equiv4 \equiv7 \equiv10 \pmod {3}$ and $n \equiv 3 \equiv 10 \pmod 7.$ Hence $n=10$.

Comment: I don't see any exponents in the original question. So Euler's theorem shouldn't really apply in any way, should it?

Comment: Just plug in your four numbers ...

Comment: @Arthur So we cannot use Euler’s theorem if the expression isn’t raised to any exponent? Shouldn’t we be still able to raise both sides of the expression and then the theorem would apply?

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes that indeed would work, however I would like to see if there would be an alternative approach. If the question wouldn’t be multiple choice I would be out of options if I cannot do anything except ”plugging in”.

Comment: @Daniel If you didn't have a multiple choice question, the theorem to use would not be Euler's, it would be the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Just use brute-force. I think it’s faster

Comment: Did it not occur to you to just *check* them? $10 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $10\equiv 2\pmod 7$ so ..... why did you think you had to do *anything*?

Comment: "Also I’m aware that we could show this just by concluding:

n≡1≡4≡7≡10(mod3)
and n≡3≡10(mod7). Hence n=10."  Then why *didn't* you?

Comment: Raising to higher powers will add extraneous solutions.  You go for a unique question $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $n\equiv 2 \pmod 7$ a question $n^2 =1\pmod 3$ and $n^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ in which *EVERY* number relative prime to $21$ will be a solution.... If you have a linear equation... just solve it linearly.  Raising to powers just too often adds extraneous incorrect solutions.  That happens in "normal" arithmetic so it occurs in modular arithmetic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eep!  I didn't realize this was multiple choice!

Sheesh!  Just *check* them.

Is $3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$?  Nope.  So that's not it.

Is $1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$? Yes.  Is $1 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$? Nope. So that's not it.

Is $7\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ Yes. Is $1 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$?  Nope.  So that's not it.

Is $10\equiv 1 \pmod 3$?  Yes.  Is $10\equiv 3 \pmod 7$. Yes.  So that's it.

That's *all* you had to do.

(Although Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us there can only be one solution $\mod 21$ [$21=3\cdot 7$]).

And Chinese Remainder THeorem says it

======

Euler's theorem is unnecessary (and inapplicable) because you have not exponents to solve

$\gcd(3,7) = 1$ so Chinese remainder Theorem tells us there is one unique solution $\mod 3\cdot 7$.  So there is a $n'; 0\le n' < 21$ where $n$ can be any value of $n' + 21m$ for any integer $k$.

And the CRT gives us a methodd of solving for $n'$ but .... I can never remember it.

But *knowing* it has a solution makes it easy to find.  $n = 1+3k= 3 + 7m$ for some $k,m$ and so $3k = 2 + 7m$ and ...

Well,  $7m\equiv -2 \pmod 3$ so $6m + m\equiv \equiv -2\pmod 3$ so let $m = 3z - 2$ for some $z$

So $3k = 2+ 7(3z-2)= -12 + 21z$ so $k= -4 + 7z$ so $k \equiv -4\pmod 7$ so let $k=-4 + 7j$ for some $j$.

So we have $3(-4 + 7j)=2+7(3z-2)$ so

$-12+ 21j = -12 + 21z$ so $j = z$.  Well, we just need *one* solution.  There are infinitely many so let $j=z =1$ so $k=3$ and $m=1$ and $n=1+3(3)= 3+7(1)=10$.  And $n\equiv 10\pmod {21}$.

So $n$ may be any $10 + 21m$ for any integer $m$.

.....

Of course back we we had $3k = 2+7m$ we should have just *seen* $3*3 = 2+7$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't say what $n$ is. However, it is easy to check which one of those options *could* be $n$: only $3$ and $10$ are $\equiv 3\pmod 7$, and $3\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$, so it must be $10$.

However, given two congruences $n\equiv a\pmod p$ and $n\equiv b\pmod q$, where $p$ and $q$ have no common factor, the Chinese remainder theorem says there is exactly one value $c\pmod{pq}$ which satisfies them both. So the general solution to your pair of congruences is $n\equiv 10\pmod{21}$.

Comment: +1 You missed a possibility: there's $17$ in addition to $3$ and $10$.

Comment: @TobyMak 17 wasn't one of the options in OP. But yes, if you weren't given options and were just using CRT then you'd check 3,10,17.

Answer (score 0):

$n\equiv3\,(mod7)\Longrightarrow n=7k+3\\
n\equiv1\,(mod3) \Longrightarrow 7k+3\equiv1\,(mod3)\,, k\equiv1\,(mod3)\\
\Longrightarrow k=3m+1$
$$n=7k+3 , k=3m+1 \Longrightarrow n= 21m+10$$
only number 10 has this condition with m=0